# Answer check $\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}(z-1)^2\lvert dz\rvert$ = $2\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$
\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}(z-1)^2\lvert dz\rvert
$$
This one is either simpler or I've have my experience jogged.

Let $z=e^{j\theta}$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ (this is the unit circle, $|z|=1$), then $\frac{dz}{d\theta}=je^{j\theta}$, so $dz=je^{j\theta}d\theta$

Clearly $\lvert dz\rvert=1\lvert d\theta\rvert = d\theta$ (as $\theta$ goes from 0 up to $2\pi$ - thiis is "A-level logic")

Anyway: $I=\int^{2\pi}_0(e^{j\theta}-1)^2d\theta=\int^{2\pi}_0(e^{2j\theta}-2e^{j\theta}+1)d\theta$

The integrals over $e^{j\theta}$ become zero,thus the answer is $2\pi$ I belive.

Comment: @tylerc0816 |j| = 1

Comment: That's fine and you're right.

Comment: It looks ok, just a little, tiny thing: some of us mathematicians feel a serious disturbance in the force whenever we see $\;j\;$ used to indicate the imaginary unit instead of our beloved $\;i\;$ , so...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution looks good and is probably the easiest way to go about.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way:**

put, $z=e^{2\pi it}$ , $0\le t \le 1$.

Then $|dz|=|2\pi i e^{2\pi it}\,dt|=2\pi \,dt=-i\frac{dz}{z}$.

Then $$\int_{|z|=1}(z-1)^2|dz|=-i\int_{|z|=1}(z-1)^2\frac{dz}{z}$$

$$=(-i).2\pi i.Res(f;0)=2\pi$$where, $f(z)=\frac{(z-1)^2}{z}$ has only singularity at $z=0$ which lies in the circle $|z|=1$.